# HighCharts using Text in yAxis instead of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beardyco/fjy6td59/) of a highchart working with number values on the yAxis but what I want to do is change it, the data I want to put in instead of `26.5` `26.5` `16.5` `26.5` is `hot` `warm` `cold`

Is there anyway to get this working as the data received from the database is formatted `hot` `warm` `cold`

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['16 Feb 15', '16 Apr 15', '27 Jul 15', '10 Nov 15', ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '°';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 4,
                    lineColor: '#666666',
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Dates',
            data: [{
                y: 26.5,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
                }
            },{
                y: 26.5,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
                }
            },{
                y: 16.5,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
                }
            },{
                y: 26.5,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
                }
            }
            ]

        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fjy6td59/1/

Comment: @artm I don't want numerics in my data

Comment: How would highcharts know 'hot' is supposed to be displayed higher than 'warm'? There needs to be a numeric value associated with the words so it can display them on the correct order.

Answer (score 5):

Are you saying that you want to just change the label text, or that you want to remove the details from the actual data points and only plot whether that temperature was 'cold', 'warm', or 'hot'?

If you only want the data to reflect those three values, use categories on the y axis, and you'll need to use the category index (0, 1, or 2) to indicate which category the data point is for

`Example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fjy6td59/2/

If you want to keep the specific data values and only change the label, you can use the label formatter with a range of values that return the appropriate label, as `artm` showed.